# Update directive's templateurl's content binding on scope's property change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

So what I am basically trying to do is make a reusable component in angularjs using directive. This directive will be a different app module(say '**childApp**'). I am injecting this  module and its dependency into my main app module. I am placing this directive in my main app's(say **mainApp**) module. What this directive does is it takes data from **mainApp's** controller and creates an isolate scope in the directive. From the link function it calls childApp's service and returns a html response and attaches it to isolate scope as say `scope.htmlresponse`<--(`htmlresponse` comes as an array). I also have a `templateurl` defined in the directive which has this code.

**templateUrl:**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li>
    <a href="" ng-click="doSomething()">
      <i class="icon"></i>SomeOperation</a>
  </li>
 </ul
 <div class="container" style="overflow-x:auto;" ng-bind-html="htmlresponse[0].htmlContent">
```

The binding takes place and the htmlresponse gets rendered in the templateurl.

**The problem starts here:**.

I also have `ul` `li` elements in the templateUrl to perform different operations as you can see in the above templateUrl's code.

**I have the link defined as such:**

```
 link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    init();  /*--**This was first call I was talking about in my question above which was returning htmlresponse**--*/
   scope.doSomething = function(){
   /*--** Makes a service call and this also returns an html response**--*/
  //example service code similar to my code
     childAppService.makeSecondServiceCall(scope.document).then(function(htmlresponse)       
     {
      renderHtml(htmlresponse);
     });
   }
 function renderHtml(responseData){
    console.log(responseData);
    if(responseData.status == 200)
      scope.htmlresponse = responseData.data;  
   }
 }
```

**Exact Issue:**
I can see the responseData as desired in console but `scope.htmlresponse = responseData.data;` is not updating the template url with new htmlresponse.
Do I need to do something else to update the binding in templateUrl? I have tried a few things from googling but It doesn't help. If anyone has encountered any such issue please guide me as to how to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the answer, however I still don't the reason. In my question I had mentioned an `init();` function inside which I was setting `scope.htmlResponse = [];` so basically every service has `.then()` as

```
.then(function(htmlresponse)       
 {
  renderHtml(htmlresponse);
 });
```

which makes them go through renderHtml(hmtlresponse) where I am setting

```
 if(responseData.status == 200)
  scope.htmlresponse = responseData.data;
```

I changed this to something like this:

```
 if(responseData.status == 200){
  scope.htmlresponse = [];
  scope.htmlresponse = responseData.data;    
 }
```

this actually made the template url div to update the binding hence the content. Strange!

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question title makes misunderstanding! `Update directive's templateurl` is more like changing the url, but what i think you mean changing template content!
The other thing is, I can't see your `ng-repeat` in template? You said your data is Array!
And the last thing is, how you use `ng-bind-html` without trusting the html content?
I suggest you to change your code into this:

```
scope.doSomething = function() {
    childAppService.makeSecondServiceCall(scope.document).then(function(res)       
                                                               {
        scope.$applyAsync(function() {
            if(res.status == 200) {
                for (var i=0, j=res.data.length; i<j; i++) {
                    res.data[i].htmlContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(res.data[i].htmlContent);
                }
                scope.htmlresponse = res.data;
            }
        });

    });
}
```

And don't forgot to inject `$sce` in your directive.
Hope to help!

Comment: I actually did this in this way :  templateUrl : <div class="container" style="overflow-x:auto;" ng-bind-html="sanitizeHtml(htmlresponse[0].htmlContent)">
and inside DDO link property scope.sanitizeHtml = function(htmlresponse){
return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlresponse);
}
Previously some of my htmlresponse was not rendering correctly also, after doing this now it is. Thanks :) and I edited the question's title.